# Getting Non HTTP response code: java.io.FileNotFoundException response code while executing jmeter test for uploading file to a server

Tags: jmeter

OS - Windows
Jmeter  version - 5.4.3

Problem - I am  trying to create a test(http multipart) to upload a file to server.
Test file and file to upload is in same directory.

Error - Non HTTP response code: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration, it should look like:

[image]

Also be aware that it's possible to just record the file upload event using your browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure that the file(s) you will be uploading is(are) copied to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more information.